# How can I accurately fuse two rectified stereo images in MATLAB for precise overlap?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I have two rectified Stereo image, which i got from Matlab App (Stereo Camera Calibration). The images below are the original (left) and rectified (right) images. I want to fuse these two images, (Fig.B2) onto (Fig.A2) and Overlap each other.
[original (left) and rectified (right) images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlNzE.jpg)

And I also got the disparity map generated by the MATLAB function disparitySGM.
[disparityMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDpvJ.jpg)

*Explain my problem*

How can I fuse two rectified stereo images ? Produces blended images with no holes or jaggies and precise overlap.

In Fig.F1, i simultaneously move the pixels of Fig.B2 by a disparity value to cover Fig.A2. It can be seen that there is accurate overlap at the red arrow, but there is obviously no accurate overlap at the blue arrow.

In Fig.F2, the steps are the same as in Example 1, but I have modified different disparity values. Then they have the opposite overlap result.

[Fusion result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19V7E.jpg)

1. [Figure A2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQDee.png)
2. [Figure B2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgGxs.png)